# Missing Icon and wrong Menu Name in PublishFromPublishingQueue Extension in Web 8

Tags: web8, gui-extensions

The PublishFromPublishingQueue extension is working properly in web 8 but the menu icon is missing and menu name is not coming properly

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question :) As far as I can tell, the extension is only marked as working for 2011 and 2013. It's likely that it needs some changes to work with Web 8.

Answer (score 1):

Following is change in Publishing.css to get icons

```
#cm_pq_publish.item .image
{

    background-image: url({ThemePath['Base']}/Sprites/base_Sprites.16px.png);
    background-position: 0 -800px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}

#cm_pq_unpublish.item .image
{

    background-image: url({ThemePath['Base']}/Sprites/base_Sprites.16px.png);
    background-position: 0px -816px;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Though it is too late to answer this question, but it might help someone in future.

Change following files

1. PublishFromPublishingQueue.config, modify:

   - `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Publishing"` to  `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, Publishing"`
   - `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, Publish"` to `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, Publish"`
   - `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Strings, UnPublish"` to `"Resources: Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.CME.Strings, UnPublish"`
2. Publish.js

   - `"tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishItems()"` to `"tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM.Publishing.PublishItems()"`
3. Unpublish.js

   - `"tridion.Web.UI.ContentManager.Publishing.UnpublishItems()"` to `"tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM.Publishing.UnpublishItems()"`

After making these changes, it is working for me in Web 8.5.